# How should I display sync information in mobile app?

Tags: mobile, ios

The product we are building requires immediate contact book sync after sign up.

Right now I have to decide how to display info that the contact book is syncing:

A. Have a small box on app UI which says - Syncing your contacts:

[image]

B. Blur the content underneath and show just the info:

[image]

C. ??

It's worth to mention that you can't play around with application while we are doing this.

What would you suggest?

*P.S. Examples are very rough sketches*

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question when you said:

> It's worth to mention that you can't play around with application while we are doing this.

Since that's the case, you need a true modal dialog which let's the user know they can't do anything until the syncing is finished.

Therefore, you have to go with **Option B**.